# Language and library tags for a question only concerning a related IDE

Tags: discussion, tags

As this isn't the first time I come across this situation and I didn't find an *exact* match here on meta, I'd like some opinions on the proper tagging of a question that's only about the use of an IDE. Here's the latest example:
[QT creator - simply show a working folder without creating QT files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44965267/2371524).

In this case, it is about "Qt Creator", an IDE specifically for C and C++ code and tailored for writing Qt applications, but not limited to it. It was originally tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile).

A very strict interpretation of tagging would suggest that the question should *only* carry the [qt-creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-creator) tag. But I don't think this is helpful (for the asker as well as for later readers) as it's a "*niche*" tag and makes the question hard to find. I found opinions on meta that *language tags* are appropriate for IDEs (or, more general, *developer tools*) related to that language as well, which sounds reasonable.

Two language tags seem to be a bit too much, though. The asker states it's about a "C/C++" project, so I assume it contains source files in both languages, but is this really relevant? It's definitely not relevant for a possible answer.

So my suggestion would be that this question should *only* carry the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, because Qt creator is primarily for Qt, which is a C++ library. Do you agree on this?

What I'm really unsure about is whether the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag should be there. There's no reference to Qt in the question at all. Does just the fact that many Qt developers might use Qt Creator justify the use of the tag? I don't think so, but I'd like to read some opinions on this.

Comment: If you have a question about Qt Creator then you must use the [qt-creator] tag.  So that users that don't know anything about it, and don't want to know anything about it, can avoid wasting their time.  Sure, all by itself it has low odds for attracting an answer, odds are currently only 1 in 4.  You can cast a wider net by also including [qt] or (uh-oh) [c++].  Never [c], that upsets people enough to post useless comments.  And of course not [makefile] when you don't use one.  But it is fairly risky, you'd better make it an entertaining question and not blow a gasket when somebody retags it.

Comment: @HansPassant note this wasn't my question, it was just my suggestion to adjust tags to [qt-creator][c++], while the one answer here still favors tagging only [qt-creator]. Both are fine for me, confirming my POV that both [qt] and [makefile] were wrong here. My doubt was that a question with *only* a "niche tag" would risk to go unnoticed even by ppl who might know an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> So my suggestion would be that this question should *only* carry the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, because Qt creator is primarily for Qt, which is a C++ library. Do you agree on this?

Absolutely not. That's not a good justification for the question having a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag. Neither is the fact that Qt Creator was written in C++. None of that has anything to do with the question.

Consider where I was using Qt Creator to write code in assembly language. Your logic would have me to tag that question [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), but that would be absurd. The question should clearly be tagged [qt-creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-creator) and [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly).

> What I'm really unsure about is whether the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag should be there. There's no reference to Qt in the question at all. Does just the fact that many Qt developers might use Qt Creator justify the use of the tag? I don't think so, but I'd like to read some opinions on this.

No, the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag doesn't belong there, either. It *only* belongs on a question if the question is actually *about* the Qt library. If the asker isn't actually *using* Qt, and if Qt isn't actually relevant to the question, then the tag doesn't belong.

> A very strict interpretation of tagging would suggest that the question should *only* carry the [qt-creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-creator) tag. But I don't think this is helpful (for the asker as well as for later readers) as it's a "*niche*" tag and makes the question hard to find. I found opinions on meta that *language tags* are appropriate for IDEs (or, more general, *developer tools*) related to that language as well, which sounds reasonable.

Well, honestly, that is my opinion here, and I'm not really known for being a tag purist or having "a very strict interpretation of tagging". The central issue in the question is how to configure the Qt Creator IDE, and therefore, that's the only tag that needs to appear on the question.

Language tags are appropriate in conjunction with IDE tags *if* you are asking a question about writing the language in that IDE. That isn't what's happening here; this question has nothing whatsoever to do with either the C or C++ language. It's just about configuring the IDE.

I also don't buy the "visibility" argument here. Sure, slapping a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and/or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag on the question would make it a *lot* more visible. But not in a way that is actually useful. In order to answer this question, someone is going to have to be familiar with the Qt Creator IDE, and those people can easily find the question by monitoring the [qt-creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-creator) tag. *Some* of the people who are knowledgeable about the Qt Creator IDE will *also* happen to be C++ programmers and therefore monitor the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, but by the same token, many of those people will also be Linux users and therefore might monitor the [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag. But that hardly justifies including the tag!

Mentioning in the body of the question that the project is in C/C++ is sufficient* to provide context. The question doesn't need either of those tags because the question isn't actually *about* either of those languages. The languages are just incidental, if they're even applicable at all. It is pretty obvious just by reading the question that the relevant configuration options that the asker needs to tweak will have nothing to do with the language(s) that are being used, even if you don't know this particular IDE and therefore don't know which ones they are.

__
<sub>* Well, no it isn't, because there is no such language. But I will assume, like you did, that this is actually a cross-language project, with source code files written in multiple languages. Alternatively, "makefile C/C++" is the description of a generic project type used by the Qt Creator IDE, in which case it should appear in quotations and *definitely* doesn't imply the presence of either language tag.</sub>

Comment: As for the language tag, consider that language tags are the primary tags searched for. I can't tell for sure, but there's a good chance this question wouldn't have an answer if [tag:c++] was omitted. I don't say any qt creator question should be tagged c++, that would of course be nonsense. But if no other language tag is applicable, as this is primarily a C++ ide, there's probably the best chance to find domain experts there. Well, it's for discussion of course and thanks for your answer!

Comment: Not all Stack Overflow questions need language tags. This is a question about using an IDE. Nothing whatsoever to do with a language.

Comment: "*Not all Stack Overflow questions need language tags.*" -- and I didn't say that ;) But a question with *only* a niche tag is [unlikely to receive any reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500325/qtcreator-how-to-store-code-indexer-settings-per-kit). I don't think that's in the spirit of this site?